# Ajax Cart Does NOT work with Full Page HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, ajax

I turned on Full Page https, so all pages load only in HTTPS. Now I realized that AJAX cart throws **error** window when I try to add somethign to the cart.

Any ideas where to look for the cause? I can post scrips if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check the ajax URL in firebug console.

Probably issue is because ajax request is goint to "http"

If **same issue found do below steps**:

1. Find out the ajax call location
2. Put the ajax URL in condition to check current URL as below:

   ```
   if (document.location.protocol == "https:") {
   /***Your https ajax request*****/
       }else{
   /***Your http ajax request*****/        
   }
   ```